# Using Group-by and case statement to determine an override to a value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to be query the table below.

```
  key         |  id  | value
-------------+------+-------+
 check-open  | 0    | ENABLED     
 check-open  | 156  | DISABLED      
 check-close | 0    | DISABLED  
 check-close | 156  | ENABLED
```

To get similar to the following.

```
 key         |  id  | value
-------------+------+-------+    
 check-open  | 156  | DISABLED       
 check-close | 156  | ENABLED

Based on a couple of rules:
 If ID=0 AND VALUE=DISABLED                                  | disabled
 If ID=0 AND VALUE=ENABLED                                   | enabled
 IF (ID=0 AND VALUE=DISABLED) AND (ID=156 AND VALUE=ENABLED) | enabled
 IF (ID=0 AND VALUE=ENABLED) AND (ID=156 AND VALUE=DISABLED) | disabled
```

So ID=0 is a default any other ID defined overrides this.

I think I'm on the right tracks but not sure how to proceed with the case statement to override if a ID other than 0 is present.

```
SELECT KEY, 
  CASE VALUE
    WHEN 'ENABLED' THEN 'DISABLED'
    ELSE 'ENABLED'
  END
FROM APPLICATION_SETTING
WHERE KEY LIKE 'opt%'
AND (ID=0 OR ID=156)
GROUP BY KEY;
```

Comment: GROUP BY usually doesn't make sense without an aggregation of some kind.

Comment: hiow is possible ID = 0 and ID = 156 ???? id can have only one value  .. you logic is noy clear ..

Comment: I don't get it. Have the rules a priority according to the order of appearance? Maybe some existential qualificators in rules may help as well.

Comment: The rules are also a little in conflict. Rule 3 is more specific than rule 1, so if evaluated in the order listed would never be applied.

Comment: You should specify the input data better. Is it possible to have just one `156  | DISABLED` row for a key?

Comment: Why not just exclude ID = 0 with `WHERE ID != 0`?

Answer (score 1):

If there's no VALUE for a specific KEY you want the default of `KEY 0`?

Assuming the KEY/ID combination is unique:

```
select 
  key,
  coalesce(max(case when id <> 0 then value end) -- check for non default value
          ,max(value)) -- otherwise use the default
from tab
FROM APPLICATION_SETTING
WHERE KEY LIKE 'opt%'
AND (ID=0 OR ID=156)
GROUP BY KEY;
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need aggregation; you need a self-join like this:

```
SELECT as0.KEY,  
   CASE WHEN asN.ID IS NULL THEN as0.VALUE
        ELSE asN.VALUE
   END AS effectiveValue
FROM APPLICATION_SETTING AS as0 
LEFT JOIN APPLICATION_SETTING AS asN
    ON as0.KEY = asN.KEY 
    AND asN.id = ? 
WHERE as0.KEY LIKE 'opt%' 
    AND as0.id = 0;
```

Where the `?` is the id value that can override the default value specified by id 0 (156 in your specific example).

*If there were multiple id's that could override, then you might need aggregation to determine which one to use, but that would be a much more complicated query.*

Answer (score 0):

You want `id` 156 to have priority over id 0.  This would be:

```
select key, value
from application_setting 
where key like '%op%' and id = 156
union all
select key, value
from application_setting s1
where key like '%op%' and id = 0 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from application_setting s2
                  where s2.key = s1.key and s2.id = 156
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have just one row with `id = 0` and one row with `id = 156` for each key then the following `SELECT` should follow the rules

```
SELECT key, MAX(id), CASE WHEN MAX(id) = 156 THEN 
          (SELECT value FROM APPLICATION_SETTING ap WHERE ap.key = key AND id = 156) ELSE
          (SELECT value FROM APPLICATION_SETTING ap WHERE ap.key = key AND id = 0) END AS VALUE
FROM APPLICATION_SETTING
WHERE KEY LIKE 'opt%' AND (ID=0 OR ID=156)
GROUP BY key
```